# AJAX - refresh certain input fields in modal after query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am new to AJAX and apologize if this has been asked before.

I am displaying editable content in a modal window which, after the user has updated it, is written back into my MySQL database. The updated content is only visible to the user after the modal is closed and the entire website is reloaded, which is a little overkill for what I need it to.

Long story short, I would like to know how can I only refresh a certain `<input> or <textarea> or <div>` field that as already a part of the opened modal AFTER the user has pressed the "Save Changes" button?

Reloading the whole page just to show an updated `input` field seems like a waste of resources.

Thanks

Current Jquery / AJAX code

```
// EDIT LOGBOOK RECORD - SAVE RECORD BUTTON
$("#EditLogButton").click(function() {

    // check that input fields are not empty
    if($("#dataProb").val()!="" && $("#dataProbCat").val()!="" && $("#dataDeptResp").val()!="" && $("#dataStatus").val()!="") {

        $.ajax({
            url: "../../plugins/MySQL/ajax_action.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: true, 
            data: { action:"update_log",LogID:$("#dataLogID").val(), Status:$("#dataStatus").val(), Problem:$("#dataProb").val(), Prob_Cat:$("#dataProbCat").val(), Dept_Resp:$("#dataDeptResp").val(), Action:$("#dataAction").val()}, //your form data to post goes here as a json object
            dataType: "html",

            success: function(data) {
                $('#problem_output').html(data);
                drawVisualization();   
            },

            error: function(data) {
            console.log(err);
            }
        });

        // close modal and refresh page
        $('#EditProblemModal').modal('hide');
        setTimeout(function(){location.reload()}, 2000);

    } else {
        //notify the user they need to enter data
        alert("Please enter a valid Category / Issue / Department / Experience.");
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether got you right. You only need to put your changes into the fields with `$('input#xy').val('yourValue');` Either you set it to data you receive from the server in the success callback, or you simply use the data from the other input field.

Comment: I get your point, however, this would AFAIK only apply if my AJAX call returns me an array with the updated data, which is not the case here. I call a query which inserts the updated data into my MySQL table, and then merely returns a success / error message. I was thinking that AJAX can merely refresh the input content and I would see the updated data. Am I wrong here?

Comment: What data should be put in which input?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong: (1) User changes some of the fields - maybe `dataStatus`? (2) Hitting the `EditLogButton` updates the status of the log id identified by `dataLogID`. (3) AJAX tells you whether the update was a success or not. Now, if AJAX did return a success, isn't the value for `dataStatus` already what was just updated in the DB. May I ask what refresh is needed? However, if I'm possibly misunderstanding something, then you'll have to change the processing of `ajax_action.php` such that, after successful update, it re-fetches the right data for that `id` and sends it back.

Comment: `However, if I'm possibly misunderstanding something, then you'll have to change the processing of ajax_action.php such that, after successful update, it re-fetches the right data for that id and sends it back` Thats it, exactly that. This basically means that after updating the DB, I have to query again, get the latest record values and send them back as an array which is then placed back into the fields. Thanks for that!